# iOS UITableView shows content of an old custom cell after reload but selecting it pushes to correct data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a very weird behavior with a `UITableViewController` in my project.

Normally it works perfectly but in one specific case it doesn't.

I have a dynamic table view with one custom type of cell. After filling all the data into the data source the table shows all the content correctly. There is a Pull-to-Refresh that updates the data source and table correctly. There are some filter buttons that update the only section with an animation correctly.
But if I click on one the detail view pushes into and if I go back click on one of these filter buttons again all the table view cells update except the ones I clicked. But if I click on this one again the detail view appears with the data of the cell that used to be there.
So the data updates just fine but the visible doesn't.
I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you

P.S: Yes I do call the `deselectRowAtIndexPath:` method in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BANF";
BANFCell *cell = (BANFCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[BANFCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// collect required data
Requisition *req;
// for right section
if ([self.tableView numberOfSections] == 1) {
    req = [recent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        req = [recent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        req = [notSent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
NSMutableArray *shortTexts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// get description text and sort short texts ascending
// also the amount and currency
NSString *reqDescript;
NSString *amount;
NSString *currency;
for (Trait *trait in req.traits) {
    if ([trait.name isEqualToString:@"DESCRIPTION"] && trait.value.length > 0) {
        reqDescript = trait.value;
    }
    if ([trait.name isEqualToString:@"TOTAL_AMOUNT"] && trait.value.length > 0) {
        amount      = trait.value;
    }
    if ([trait.name isEqualToString:@"CURRENCY"] && trait.value.length > 0) {
        currency    = trait.value;
    }
}
NSString *amountAndCurreny;
if (amount) {
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [currencyFormatter setCurrencyCode:currency];
    amountAndCurreny  = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:amount.doubleValue]];
} else
    amountAndCurreny  = @"";
cell.amountLabel.text = amountAndCurreny;

NSArray *descriptors  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"itm_number"
                                                                              ascending:YES], nil];
NSArray *orderedArray = [req.positions sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
for (Position *position in orderedArray) {
    for (Trait *trait in position.traits) {
        if ([trait.name isEqualToString:@"SHORT_TEXT"] && trait.value.length > 0) {
            [shortTexts addObject:trait.value];
        }
    }
}
UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tableBG"];
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage];
// filling them in
if (req.iD.integerValue < 0) {
    [cell.histLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"New", nil)];
} else {
    [cell.histLabel setText:req.iD.stringValue];
}
[cell.datelabel setText:[labelDateFormatter stringFromDate:req.createDate]];

switch (req.status) {
    case ReqStatusNew:          [cell.imageView setImage:nil];
        break;
    case ReqStatusSaved:        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"istGespeichertKiste.png"]];
        break;
    case ReqStatusApproved:     [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"genehmigtKiste.png"]];
        break;
    case ReqStatusInWFF:        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"workflowKiste.png"]];
        break;
    case ReqStatusNotApproved:  [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abgelehntKiste.png"]];
        break;
    case ReqStatusOrdered:      [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"istBestelltKiste.png"]];
        break;
    case ReqStatusDelivered:    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"geliefertKiste.png"]];
        break;
}
cell.shortTextLabel.marqueeType = MLContinuous;
cell.shortTextLabel.rate = 50;
cell.shortTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
if (reqDescript == nil) {
    cell.shortTextLabel.text = [shortTexts componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
} else if (shortTexts.count > 0) {
    cell.shortTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", reqDescript, [shortTexts componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];
} else {
    cell.shortTextLabel.text = reqDescript;
}
[cell.shortTextLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(56, 35, 168, 18)];
return cell;
}
```

In `viewWillAppear:` I just set the buttons in the navigationcontroller and call
`[tableview reloadData]`
In `viewDidLoad:` just adding the delegate of the refresh control

The refresh control just calls `[tableview reloadData]` after updating the `recent` and `notSent` arrays from Core Data

A filter button just calls:

```
- (IBAction)filterPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
sender.selected = !sender.selected;
NSArray *filters = [dvFilterList componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[filters objectAtIndex:sender.tag]]){
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO
                                            forKey:[filters objectAtIndex:sender.tag]];
} else {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES
                                            forKey:[filters objectAtIndex:sender.tag]];
}
[self updateTableViewData];
// only the section with the recent banfs
NSInteger section = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView] - 1;
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section]
              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

(`updateTableViewData` is the method that just updates the `recent` and `notSent` arrays from Core Data)

Comment: put code of cellForRowAtIndexPath..

Comment: `deselectRowAtIndexPath` is only responsible for just that - *disabling the selection*. It does not trigger content reload. Are you using some kind of caching for the custom cells once they are created? Please, post relevant portions of code (dataSource and delegate).

Comment: Please show us some code, Our crystal balls are out for maintenance. Especially cellForRowAtIndexPath: would be interesting.

Comment: put code, how you update your data

Comment: sorry just updated the post with data

Comment: Show viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad and where you are reloading table?

Comment: Just updated the post again with more code, thank you all for trying to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution by myself.
In my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method I call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` and by giving the selected row as sender variable Xcode is somehow saving just the look of the cell in background that can only be deleted by removing the whole view controller from the stack.
Now I just give `self` as the sender because I don't need the variable.
So I code this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToReq" sender:self];
```

Instead of this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToReq" sender:[self tableView:tableView
                                             cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this    ,

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

You can write this in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
BANFCell *cell = (BANFCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil

                                                         forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: reloadData I'm just using, but like described it only doesn't work in one case, the second one just crashes my app

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer for the original question, but might help someone else seeing similar problems.

I've encountered similar behavior with buggy code like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (condition)
    {
        CustomCell1* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"custom1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //  configure cell
        //  !! note how "return cell;" is missing !!
    }

    CustomCell2* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"custom2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //  configure cell
    return cell; 
}
```

Was fixed by actually returning the special-case cell from the conditional branch.